# How do i take thread dump for specific time interval

Tags: java

I want to take thread dump for say last 10 min or 30 min , how can I do that via command line

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "last 10 min"? A thread dump is for a given moment, not a duration.

Comment: I mean from current time to next 10 min or from current time to last 10 min

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.